# Digital signature in Android 2.3

Tags: android, digital-signature

I have to develop a digital signature App in Android which allows to sign a document with a private key, it is fairly simple with Andorid 4.0 since there are an specific library to do that called android.security, but in lower APIs it doesn't exist.

The main problem is extracting the credentials from the phone, with Android 4.0 this is really easy with "KeyChan" class, but in Andorid 2.3 I am completely lost.

I can reuse the whole code but the classes:

- android.security.KeyChain;
- android.security.KeyChainAliasCallback;
- android.security.KeyChainException;

Any idea or suggestion? Does anybody know if there is any library similar to "android.security" in Android 2.3?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a huge research I find out that is impossible to get access to the default device's KeyStore (actually is possible but just to get CA certificates not custom) before 4.0, the best solution is the creation of your default KeyStore in Java for your app.